# Reload table after request was finished

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsurlsession

I have a table view that use result of fetching data with `NSURLSession` as a datasource. Here is my `NSArray` which is responsible about that table.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *results;
```

And this is my delegate and datasource method

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_results count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    WordResult *word = (WordResult *)[_results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = word.defid;

    return cell;
}
```

In my `viewDidLoad`, I fetched request from [Mashape](https://market.mashape.com/community/urban-dictionary) and try to map the result into my custom class `WordResult`
Here is my fetch method

```
#pragma mark - GET Request
- (void)fetchDataFromMashape:(NSURL *)URL {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:API_KEY_MASHAPE forHTTPHeaderField:API_MASHAPE_HEADER_1];
    [request setValue:API_ACCEPT forHTTPHeaderField:API_MASHAPE_HEADER_2];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        self.results = [self processResultData:jsonResult];
    }];

    [task resume];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)processResultData:(NSDictionary *)dict {

    NSArray *list = [dict objectForKey:@"list"];
    NSMutableArray *tempListOfWord = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (list) {
        for (NSDictionary *item in list) {
            WordResult *word = [[WordResult alloc] initWithDictionary:item];
            [tempListOfWord addObject:word];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Result array of word: %@", tempListOfWord);
    return tempListOfWord;
}
```

My problem is, I dont know where to reload data after my result array was assigned by fetch method and dismissing my progress HUD that I showed on my `viewDidLoad`.
Here is my viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [SVProgressHUD show];
    [self fetchDataFromMashape:_finalURLrequest];

}
```

So where should I put `[SVProgressHUD dismiss]` and `[self.tableView reloadData]` after my request has been finished?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should dismiss your [SVProgressHUD dismiss] above the return and then reload your tableview [self.tableView reloadData]

Comment: Already tried in my `processResultData` right before return, but it doesnt work @KamleshShingarakhiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload your table on main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Wasif Saood. I did it in main queue and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can put `[SVProgress dismmis]` and also reload your tableview `[self.tableView reloadData]` after `self.results = [self processResultData:jsonResult];`

Comment: STRANGE. Did you get this log NSLog(@"Result array of word: %@", tempListOfWord); ?

Answer (score 0):

A great tableView coding pattern is putting `reload` call in `setters` of model objects, then you won't miss any data change. For example setter for `result` in your case:

```
-(void)setResult:(NSMutableArray*)result{
  _result = result;
  [self.tableView reloadData]
  [SVProgressHUD dismiss]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your viewdidload before calling fetchdata do

```
self.results=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

And then call your `[self.tableView reloadData]` within the completion block after assigning the array with data

And then  call svprogress hud hide method outside the block after `[task resume]`  in the fetch data function